# How to execute python tkinter button without clicking mouse

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a button widget:

```py
button.configure(command=some command)
```

By clicking on the button it can run in runtime(when it is in the mainloop instruction). Now I want to execute the button without clicking mouse. Is there any instruction or process to execute the button widget without click?

Comment: it would be helpful if you could post a simple code sample containing the minimum needed to demonstrate the problem, and a better explanation of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @JamesKent: He provided all necessary information. I don't see what else he would have to add that would make the question more clear or easier to answer.

Comment: I am puzzled about the hold also. This is a clear question with a clear answer (the .invoke() method), that is much better than simulatating a click event over the rectangle occupied by button.

Comment: After execution of any Tkinter programme controls enter to mainloop and wait for mouse or keyboard. we can use button.configure option to active the button at runtime and control will exit from mainloop. but to execute the button we have to click on the button.I am asking for the information that is there any other option to activate the button widgets without using hardware. Or can i exit from the mainloop without closing the window or button click.actually i want to use the mainloop within a infinite loop.so I want to exit from the mainloop to execute the instructions repetitively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `invoke()` method of the `Button` widget, for example ([docs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/button.htm#M17)):

```py
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

t = Tk()

def button1_click():
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Message", "Bang!")

def button2_click():
    button1.invoke()

button1 = Button(t, text="Button 1", command=button1_click)
button1.pack()

button2 = Button(t, text="Button 2", command=button2_click)
button2.pack()

mainloop()
```

Styled buttons:

```py
import tkFont
font = tkFont.Font(size=32, weight="bold")

button['bg'] = "red"
button['fg'] = "white"
button['font'] = font
```

Comment: After execution of any Tkinter programme controls enter to mainloop and wait for mouse or keyboard. we can use button.configure option to active the button at runtime and control will exit from mainloop. but to execute the button we have to click on the button.I am asking for the information that is there any other option to activate the button widgets without using hardware. Or can i exit from the mainloop without closing the window or button click.actually i want to use the mainloop within a infinite loop.so I want to exit from the mainloop to execute the instructions repetitively.

Comment: my problem is solved by using after instruction. thank you for your help.

Comment: sir how to resize the text entered in the tk window how to use large front and bold and colour front.

Comment: thank you sir. it works fine.please help me how to move tickers continuously at the bottom of tkinter window. at the same time it will  monitor the GPIO input from raspberry pi GPIO pin.when a switch is pressed it will show some result in tkinter window. I have written a code. it monitors GPIO pin and providing output. problem is that when tickers is moving then it is not monitoring the GPIO pin and vice-versa. I want to do this two process simultaneously as it is done in most news channel.tickers will move independently with other display part of that window